# AddForce changes behavior based on location

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an enemy jump toward its target to attack using `AddForce`, but just how much force is added seems to depend greatly on where in the scene the entities are ([see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBSGNyAit_4)).

What could the issue be?

```
void Start(){
    ani = GetComponent<Animation>();
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    state = states.idle;
}

private void Attack(){
    state = states.attack;
    agent.enabled = false;
    ani.Play("attack3");
    Vector3 force = transform.forward * 300f;
    force.y = 750f;
    rig.AddForce(force);
}
```

Comment: I am thinking it has to do with how you call the Attack method. Most likely in the first case of your video, the method is called once while in the second case, it happens to be called over several frames. You should provide the whole AI script, maybe via some dropbox or else.

Comment: Agreed, can you paste the script that calls the attack method please

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's hard to say, but there's one thing that does stand out to me: if your entity is rotated around the x-axis (i.e. could be angled upward or downward) then you'd see the behaviour you describe from the code you have. (It's not clear from your video whether this is the case or not, but it does seem that your ground has some slope to it which *could* cause this if the models were aligned to the floor.)

Consider: if your agent is facing directly along the Z axis then its `transform.forward` will have a `y` of zero. The initial value of `force` will have a magnitude of `300` (and will still have a `y` of zero). You will then set that `y` to `750` giving an overall force of `(0, 750, 300)`.

Now consider that your agent is facing almost completely upward. `transform.forward` is now `(0, 299, 0.01)` and you multiply by 300, but then set `y = 750`. Your resulting force is now `(0, 750, 3)` for an agent that's jumping in the same direction.

You could fix this by modifying the end of `Attack` like so:

```
Vector3 horizontalDirection = new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0, transform.forward.z);
Vector3 force = horizontalDirection.normalized * 300f;
force.y = 750f;
rig.AddForce(force);
```

The above code guarantees the magnitude of `force` will be consistent no matter which direction your character is facing.

(The other issue mentioned in comment by @fafase is a very plausible cause also, and it could be one or both of these to blame!)